# Symfony docker not properly creating container

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose

I'm trying to make a docker environmment for symfony but it seems like the symfony container is not properly created and i can't get why

```
clong@christopher-laptop:~/Desktop/projects/private/MyProject$ make start
docker-compose up -d
Creating network "myproject_symfony-network" with the default driver
Creating myproject_database_1 ... done
Creating myproject_symfony_1    ... done
Creating myproject_phpmyadmin_1 ... done
```

```
clong@christopher-laptop:~/Desktop/projects/private/MyProject$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                   NAMES
c48b724e4e50   phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   58 seconds ago   Up 57 seconds   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp   myproject_phpmyadmin_1
ebffb3ab9608   mysql:latest            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   59 seconds ago   Up 58 seconds   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                     myproject_database_1
```

As a result if I try to access the container it's failing (which seems to be normal as it's not even appearing in docker ps)

```
make bash
docker-compose exec symfony bash
ERROR: No container found for symfony_1
make: *** [Makefile:11: bash] Error 1
```

As a start i made a simple `Makefile`

```
build:
    docker-compose build

start:
    docker-compose up -d

stop:
    docker-compose down

bash:
    docker-compose exec symfony bash

install:
    docker-compose exec symfony composer install

migrate:
    docker-compose exec symfony bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
```

Then I defined `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  symfony:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - symfony-network
  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony_db
      MYSQL_USER: clong
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: clong123
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root123
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - symfony-network

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_USER: clong
      PMA_PASSWORD: clong123
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - symfony-network

networks:
  symfony-network:

volumes:
  db-data:
```

And finally here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:latest

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl zip pdo_mysql

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install Symfony CLI
RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
ENV PATH="/root/.symfony/bin:${PATH}"

# Set up the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 8000

# Start the Symfony development server
CMD symfony server:start --no-tls
```